# Change ID values in the result set of a mysql join

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have 2 tables, books and genre_order. I'm trying to select all values from books(t1) and order them by genre using order column from genre_order(t2) using a JOIN. The result set orders them just fine, however, I'm in the dark about how to change book_id to reflect the new order.

```
table : books
+-------+------------------+-----------+
|book_id|   name           |   genre   |
+-------+------------------+-----------+
|   1   |   Harry Potter   |  Fantasy  |
|   2   |   The Alchemist  |  Fantasy  |
|   3   |   Inferno        |  Thriller |
|   4   |   Steve Jobs     |  Biography|
|   5   |   John Adams     |  Biography|
+-------+------------------+-----------+


table : genre_order
+-----------+-------+
|   genre   | order |
+-----------+-------+
| Biography |  1    |
| Fantasy   |  2    |
| Thriller  |  3    |
+-----------+-------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM books t1 JOIN genre_order t2 ON t1.genre = t2.genre ORDER BY t2.order ASC
```

result:

```
  +-------+------------------+-----------+-----------+------+
  |book_id|   name           |   genre   |  genre    | order|
  +-------+------------------+-----------+-----------+------+
  |   4   |   Steve Jobs     |  Biography|  Biography|  1   |
  |   5   |   John Adams     |  Biography|  Biography|  1   |
  |   1   |   Harry Potter   |  Fantasy  |  Fantasy  |  2   |
  |   2   |   The Alchemist  |  Fantasy  |  Fantasy  |  2   |
  |   3   |   Inferno        |  Thriller |  Thriller |  3   |
  +-------+------------------+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Expected result:

```
  +-------+------------------+-----------+------+
  |book_id|   name           |   genre   | order|
  +-------+------------------+-----------+------+
  |   1   |   Steve Jobs     |  Biography|  1   |
  |   2   |   John Adams     |  Biography|  1   |
  |   3   |   Harry Potter   |  Fantasy  |  2   |
  |   4   |   The Alchemist  |  Fantasy  |  2   |
  |   5   |   Inferno        |  Thriller |  3   |
  +-------+------------------+-----------+------+
```

Is it possible to change book_id in the result set?. Also, how do I avoid redundant columns?

Comment: can you add a schema(what do you want) like as result?

Comment: 'Also, how do I avoid redundant columns?' specify column names rather than *.  'Is it possible to change book_id in the result set' - yes it is but i'm not clear if you want 1,2,3,4,5 or 1,2,1,2,1

Comment: @Tushar I edited to show expected result

Comment: @P.Salmon I hadn't thought of that, thanks.

Comment: @JonZee I added an answer, hopefully 2nd query will be work successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by pk_field ) as book_id,t1.name,t2.genre,t2.order FROM books t1 JOIN genre_order t2 ON t1.genre = t2.genre ORDER BY t2.order ASC
```

Or This code

```
select  @ab:=@ab+1 as book_id,a.* from (SELECT t1.name,t2.genre,t2.order FROM books t1 JOIN genre_order t2 ON t1.genre = t2.genre ORDER BY t2.order DESC) a, (SELECT @ab:= 0) AS ab
```

Comment: The 2nd query works in terms of getting rid of the redundant column but not the id order

Comment: Ok. Try now. Hopefully it will be work now. I changed it on your reply.

Comment: It works now, thanks. Also if you can please share a link to where I can read more about this to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp 

Read here and practice more and more. Best of luck

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable as a table and cross join it with the source table:

```
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS book_id, t1.* 
FROM books t1, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t 
JOIN genre_order t2 ON t1.genre = t2.genre 
ORDER BY t2.order ASC
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it